# Why are data and computed values undefined/NaN in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, minesweeper

I am a Vue and JS beginner and am trying to create Minesweeper using Vue3. At the moment, I'm trying to implement a watcher that will notify the player that they have won if `cellsLeft` (the number of non-mine cells left) reaches 0. However, it seems like my computed value for `cellsLeft` is `NaN` and I don't understand why.

This is what the data & computed for my `MinesweeperGame.vue` looks like:

```
import MinesweeperCell from "./MinesweeperCell.vue";
import GameToolbar from "./GameToolbar.vue";

export default {
  props: {
    width: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 10,
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 10,
    },
    numBombs: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 15,
    },
  },
  components: { MinesweeperCell, GameToolbar },
  data() {
    return {
      numCells: this.height * this.width,
      numRevealed: 0,
      field: this.createField(),
    };
  },
  computed: {
    cellsLeft() {
      return this.numCells - this.Bombs - this.numRevealed
    }
  },
  watch: {
    cellsLeft(value) {
      console.log(this.cellsLeft)
      if (value === 0) {
        alert("You Won!");
      }
    },
  },
```

Here's the method in which `numRevealed` is updated. Whenever a separate child component, `MinesweeperCell`, is clicked on and revealed, `numRevealed` is increased by 1. Here's that code:

```
cellRevealed(coords, isMine, label) {
      if (isMine) {
        alert("Game Over!");
      } else {
        // decrease num of cells left
        this.numRevealed += 1
        console.log(this.cellsLeft)
        // if there are no bombs around, reveal all neighbors
        if (label === "0") {
          const neighbors = this.getNeighbors(coords[0], coords[1]);
          const that = this;
          neighbors.forEach(function (coords) {
            const refNum = that.getRefNum(coords[0], coords[1]);
            const neighborCell = that.$refs.cells[refNum];
            neighborCell.reveal();
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `this.Bombs` seems `undefined` use `this.numBombs`

Comment: @wendt88 that was it thank you so much! oops!